Integrating over a dynamic region
Given functions I(x,t) and v(x,t), I want to numerically approximate T(x), given by

where

what is the best way to implement this in Python? I essentially need a way of approximating T(x) in the most efficient way, given some expression for both I(x,t) and v(x,t).
